# Function as an argument in a function

Tags: python, function

So here is the the problem

```
def func_1(x):
     print 'function'

def func_2(x,y):
     print 'function2'

def func_3():
     n=func_1(x)
     m=func_2(x,y)
```

i have 2 functions and i have a third one which needs to use the first 2 , the problem is that i don't know how to make it work . I give the arguments of the first two functions and it gives me an error , tried giving the functions as an argument , but it gives me a syntax error

i also tried of getting rid of the first function , solving the problem with a while cycle like this

```
counter = 0
while counter<10:
     n=func_1(x)
     m=func_2(x,y)
```

but it tells me that tuple object is not callable 
If someone could tell me how to do it without defining the first 2 functions inside the third one i would be grateful

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: No, the problem is larger than that. Show the code, what you expect, and what you actually get.

Answer (score 5):

You are not passing `func_3()` any arguments, and still expecting it to know `x` and `y`

Also `func_1 ()` and `func_2` doen't return anything, so there is no need to do `value = func()` at `func_3()`

Try this:

```
def func_1(x):
    print "i'm func1"
    print x

def func_2(x,y):
    print "i'm func2"
    print x, y

def func_3(x, y):
    func_1(x)
    func_2(x, y)

func_3(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you are trying to get func3 to use functions passed as arguments? Something like

```
def func1(x):
    return 2*x

def func2(x, y):
    return 3*x + 2*y

def func3(x, y, fn1, fn2):
    return fn1(x) + fn2(x, y)

def main():
    print(5, 8, func1, func2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```